# Node.js Express get app properties in router

Tags: node.js, express

Is there an easy way to access parameters set using app.set() from the context of a router? I was hoping router.get would work but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A router itself does not have access to the `app` object as far as I know.  But, you can get the `app` object from any request handler on the router via `req.app`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set("greeting", "hello");

const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.app.get("greeting"));   // outputs "hello"
});

app.use(router);
app.listen(80);
```

It works this way because a router doesn't actually know the `app` it is part of and isn't necessarily used by only one `app` object.  In fact, it could even be used by multiple separate app objects.  Instead, it is the `app` that knows who its routers are and when routing to the router, it sets `req.app` when it prepares the `req` object for routing.